# How to get the token value from meta tag in a outlet page - Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal-7, meta-tags

I need to display the meta tag values from the meta tag tokens.

My Code:

```
function MyModule_html_head_alter(&$head_elements) {
    $head_elements['metatag_description']['#value'] = $outlet_description; 
}
```

Actual Output:

```
[node:node_sections] - [node:field_lead_text] Testing
```

Expecting Output:

```
   Food - Testing lead text Testing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [token_replace](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21token.inc/function/token_replace/7.x) function

```
$menu = menu_get_item();
  if($menu['path'] == 'node/%') { // check if you are on node page
    $node = $menu['page arguments'][0];
    $head_elements['metatag_description']['#value'] = token_replace($outlet_description, array('node' => $node));
  }
```